# How to add styleDependent names programmatically?

Tags: java, css, gwt

I'm trying to create a separate Button css class, that should be accessible by a `ClientBundle`. My goal is to change button styles programmatically by application state.

The following applies the button style, but does not change the background, so somehow the `-ok` dependent stylename is not taken into account. Why?

```
.myButton {
    background: white;
}

.myButton-ok {
    background: green;
}

public interface MyButtonResource extends ClientBundle {
    public static final MyButtonResource INSTANCE = GWT.create(MyButtonResource.class);

    @Source("MyButtonResource.css")
    Style css();

    interface Style extends CssResource {
        @ClassName("myButton")
        String buttonStyle();

        @ClassName("myButton-ok")
        String buttonStyleOK();
    }
}


MyButtonResource.INSTANCE.css().ensureInjected();
setStyleName(MyButtonResource.INSTANCE.css().buttonStyle());
button.addStyleDependentName(MyButtonResource.INSTANCE.css().buttonStyleOK());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `addStyleDependentName` with obfuscated css resources, see this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4746)

The problem is that the `addStyleDependentName` appends a suffix `-ok` to the current style `button` setting the style of the element to `button-ok`

But when obfuscator acts, in your resource you will result `AA` for `button` and `AB` for `button-ok`. In consequence after applying your code in the OK status your button will have `AA-AB` which does not match any rule in your css section.

The only way to face this, is adding a second style to your widget, I would do:

button.addStyleName(MyButtonResource.INSTANCE.css().buttonStyleOK());